# How to understand the output of callgrind using Kcachegrind

Tags: c++, valgrind, kcachegrind, callgrind

When profiling the log Kcachegrind shows %of inclusive as 13.92%. Should it not be close to 100% as mentioned in the [FAQ Q:1](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/show.cgi/KcacheGrindFAQ)??

Here is the screenshot of the profile log

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily.

`main` is not the "real" entry point of your program, there is lot of stuff going on before and after, for example loading/unloading DLLs and the construction/destruction of globals (those which are dynamically initialized).

Those things take time, although normally negligible.

Note that there are flags for callgrind that allow to start the collection of statistics at the start of a function (for example `main`) depending on what you are really interested in.